# zend_dom_query undefined method

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am simply building a script that checks a page for certain content, and I am running into a problem with the Zend methods. Here is the function in question:

```
function parse_html($html) {

    $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
    $table_rows = $dom->query('tr');

    foreach ($table_rows as $table_row) {
         $table_row->query('td.startTimeDateColumnHeader')->nodeValue;
    }

}
```

However I am getting this error:

`Call to undefined method DOMElement::query()`

in regard to this line:

```
$table_row->query('.startTimeDateColumnHeader')->nodeValue;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is telling you that the php class [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) does not have a method named query that is callable.

To explain: you performed a query on a DOM document using [Zend_Dom_Query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.query.html) the result returned was in the form of [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) and [DOMNodes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) so query() is no longer available.

You'll probably need to do something like:

```
$table_row->getAttribute('.startTimeDateColumnHeader');
```

I may have selected the wrong method, but I hope you get the idea.